# Conditional signing with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using Inno Setup 6.0.3 and would like to control whether to sign the (un)installer via command-line. At the moment, my `Setup.iss` looks like this:

```
SignedUninstaller=true
SignTool=...
```

I would like to disable signing via a parameter/environment variable/whatever.

How can I do this?

The reason for this is that I'd like to disable signing on our developer workstations, whereas on our CI server the (un)installer should be signed.

Comment: See [How to optionally include certain code for certain features?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21538278/850848)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InnoSetup compiler fully supports command line custom parameters, as exaplined in its [Guide](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=compilercmdline).

So you can define your own custom parameter within your `Setup.iss` file:

```
; CASE 1) "iscc.exe Setup.iss /DSIGN_UNINSTALLER=1"  -> SIGN UNINSTALLER
; CASE 2) "iscc.exe Setup.iss                       -> SIGN UNINSTALLER
; CASE 3) "iscc.exe Setup.iss /DSIGN_UNINSTALLER=0"  -> DOES NOT SIGN UNINSTALLER
; Enable by default (case 2)
#ifndef SIGN_UNINSTALLER
  #define SIGN_UNINSTALLER "1"
#endif

...

#if SIGN_UNINSTALLER == "1"
  SignedUninstaller=true
  SignTool=...
#endif
```

Comment: I've also found this solution a couple of minutes ago on my own - you were faster posting yours  But thank you very much !

Comment: glad to know it helps :)

Comment: Imo, more common is to base the choice on a mere presence of the parameter/define, rather then using 1/0: `#ifdef SIGN_UNINSTALLER` `SignedUninstaller=true` `SignTool=...` `#endif` and then use it like `iscc Setup.iss /DSIGN_UNINSTALLER`.